# How to get every web request go though a secured Proxy?

Tags: networking, apt, proxy

I am connecting to Internet though a **Secured Proxy Server** (using a Proxy Authentication). 
I already set the proxy system wide, added the authentication Username and password in apt.conf file.
All I want now is that all my apps should go through the desired proxy server **along with authentication**.
For instance when i try to add an online Facebook account, it doesnt work.